# How can I solve 'Element type is invalid' error when running Astro build with React components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, astrojs

Tried running astro build in my astro project with a few react components but got this error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
  File:
    C:\Users\user\Desktop\personal projects\churchweb\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:77:77
  Code:
    76 | b,d);return;case $b:c=c.type;d=Wc(c,d);Xc(a,b,c,d,f);return;case Vb:f=d.children;c=c._context;d=d.value;e=c._currentValue;c._currentValue=d;g=P;P=d={parent:g,depth:null===g?0:g.depth+1,context:c,parentValue:e,value:d};b.context=d;Z(a,b,f);a=P;if(null===a)throw Error("Tried to pop a Context at the root of the app. This is a bug in React.");d=a.parentValue;a.context._currentValue=d===ec?a.context._defaultValue:d;a=P=a.parent;b.context=a;return;case Wb:d=d.children;d=d(c._currentValue);Z(a,b,d);return;
    > 77 | case ac:f=c._init;c=f(c._payload);d=Wc(c,d);Xc(a,b,c,d,void 0);return}throw Error("Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: "+((null==c?c:typeof c)+"."));}}
         |                                                                             ^
      78 | function Z(a,b,c){b.node=c;if("object"===typeof c&&null!==c){switch(c.$$typeof){case Qb:Xc(a,b,c.type,c.props,c.ref);return;case Rb:throw Error("Portals are not currently supported by the server renderer. Render them conditionally so that they only appear on the client render.");case ac:var d=c._init;c=d(c._payload);Z(a,b,c);return}if(qa(c)){$c(a,b,c);return}null===c||"object"!==typeof c?d=null:(d=fc&&c[fc]||c["@@iterator"],d="function"===typeof d?d:null);if(d&&(d=d.call(c))){c=d.next();if(!c.done){var f=
      79 | [];do f.push(c.value),c=d.next();while(!c.done);$c(a,b,f)}return}a=Object.prototype.toString.call(c);throw Error("Objects are not valid as a React child (found: "+("[object Object]"===a?"object with keys {"+Object.keys(c).join(", ")+"}":a)+"). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.");}"string"===typeof c?(d=b.blockedSegment,d.lastPushedText=Aa(b.blockedSegment.chunks,c,a.responseState,d.lastPushedText)):"number"===typeof c&&(d=b.blockedSegment,d.lastPushedText=Aa(b.blockedSegment.chunks,
      80 | ""+c,a.responseState,d.lastPushedText))}function $c(a,b,c){for(var d=c.length,f=0;f<d;f++){var e=b.treeContext;b.treeContext=rc(e,d,f);try{Yc(a,b,c[f])}finally{b.treeContext=e}}}
```